# Application similar to MS Paint to do graphical work on Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

This is going to sound silly to someone who does this everyday.. but I am confused about something.

What do people use to do similar things like with MS Paint (not Paint.net), e.g. stuff like making rage comics and meme's or other such silly things. The only graphics application I found for my Mac is GIMP

Comment: Software recommendation are difficult to give, especially without knowing your detailed requirements. Did you browse through the Mac App Store already, there are a lot of "graphics" apps there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most similar to MS Paint that I've seen is [Paintbrush](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net).

[image: Screenshot from Paintrbrush website]

Comment: You're awesome :) Works great!